# Error when box plot

Tags: visualization, matplotlib

Code:

```
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (6,6))
    ax = fig.gca()
    auto_price.loc[:, ['price', 'fuel-type', 'aspiration']].boxplot(by = 'fuel-type', 'aspiration', ax = ax)
    ax.set_title('Box plot of price new')
    ax.set_ylabel('Auto Price')
    ax.set_ylim(0.0, 50000.0)
    plt.show()
```

---

```
Error:
  File "<ipython-input-20-0712de0416f5>", line 3
    auto_price.loc[:, ['price', 'fuel-type', 'aspiration']].boxplot(by = 'fuel-type', 'aspiration', ax = ax, yx = yx)
                                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

---

Background/additional information:

Following code works fine:

```
    fig = plt.figure(figsize =(5,5))
    ax = fig.gca()
    auto_price.loc[:,['price', 'horsepower']].boxplot(by = 'horsepower', ax = ax)
    ax.set_title('Box plot of price')
    ax.set_ylabel('Auto Price')
    ax.set_ylim(0.0, 50000.0)
```

Comment: All lines of code should be indented four spaces. All indents after that will be preserved. This makes Python code, in particular, much easier to read.

Comment: You cannot first pass parameters exclusively and then implicitly

Comment: @Aditya, what do you mean by 'exclusively' and then 'implicitly'?

Comment: Like you are passing by, ax via an = and aspiration like that, the variables need to match their defined order

Comment: so how should i change the code to make it work? I am not sure i understand how to make the edit.

Answer (score 2):

As the error message suggests, your error is caused by passing **positional argument** after **keyword argument**.

Consider a function

```
def foo(a,b,c):
    return a+b*c
```

You can call this function by `foo(3,4,5)` and it returns 23. In this case, all three arguments are **positional argument**s, and Python understand  them by their position: `3` is the first argument, therefore corresponds to `a`. Similarly `4` for `b` and `5` for `c`.

You can also call this function by `foo(b=3,a=4,c=5)` and it returns 19. Here all three arguments are **keyword argument**s, in the sense that `3` is identified as for `b` because of the keyword, instead of its position.

You can mix the two kinds of arguments, but **positional argument**s must come before **keyword argument**, e.g. `foo(3,c=4,b=5)`. There is no confusion here: `3` comes without a keyword, so it is interpreted by its position, therefore `3` is for `a`.

You cannot write **keyword argument** before **position argument**. For instance if you call `foo(c=3,4,5)`, Python got confused: I know `3` is for `c`, but is `4` for `a` or `b`? So if you write like this, you get the error message

```
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

Therefore in your code `boxplot(by = 'fuel-type', 'aspiration', ax = ax)`, you passed positional argument `'aspiration'` after keyword argument `by = 'fuel-type'`, causing this error.

To fix, just call `'aspiration'` by its keyword as well, i.e. `KEYWORD='aspiration'`.